# How to set closure to capsule global variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following functions,in which I can set prompt when someone leave page while inputting some values.

My consern is how to encapsule `checkFlag`. in this case, `checkFlag` is treated as global variables.

So that it is somewhat inconvenient.

```
let checkFlag = false;

const onBeforeunloadHandler = function(e) {
    var msg = '';
    e.returnValue = msg;
};

const formAlert = function() {
    if(!checkFlag) {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', onBeforeunloadHandler);
        for(var i = 0; i < checkValue.length; i++) {
            checkValue[i].removeEventListener('input', formAlert);
            checkValue[i].removeEventListener('change', formAlert);
        }
        checkFlag = true;
    }
};


(() => {
    let checkValue = document.querySelectorAll( "input[form='test'], textarea[form='test']");
    let submitBtn = document.querySelector('button[type="button"]');
    
    for(var i = 0; i < checkValue.length; i++) {
      checkValue[i].addEventListener('input', formAlert);
      checkValue[i].addEventListener('change', formAlert);
    }
    submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', onBeforeunloadHandler);
    });
})();
```

If someone has opinion, will you please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for anything in the outer scope. You can put it all into the IIFE.

```
(() => {
    let checkFlag = false;

    const onBeforeunloadHandler = function(e) {
        var msg = '';
        e.returnValue = msg;
    };

    const formAlert = function() {
        if(!checkFlag) {
            window.addEventListener('beforeunload', onBeforeunloadHandler);
            for(var i = 0; i < checkValue.length; i++) {
                checkValue[i].removeEventListener('input', formAlert);
                checkValue[i].removeEventListener('change', formAlert);
            }
            checkFlag = true;
        }
    };


    let checkValue = document.querySelectorAll( "input[form='test'], textarea[form='test']");
    let submitBtn = document.querySelector('button[type="button"]');
    
    for(var i = 0; i < checkValue.length; i++) {
      checkValue[i].addEventListener('input', formAlert);
      checkValue[i].addEventListener('change', formAlert);
    }
    submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', onBeforeunloadHandler);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

(() => {
let checkFlag = false;

```
const onBeforeunloadHandler = function(e) {
    var msg = '';
    e.returnValue = msg;
};

const formAlert = function() {
    if(!checkFlag) {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', onBeforeunloadHandler);
        for(var i = 0; i < checkValue.length; i++) {
            checkValue[i].removeEventListener('input', formAlert);
            checkValue[i].removeEventListener('change', formAlert);
        }
        checkFlag = true;
    }
};


let checkValue = document.querySelectorAll( "input[form='test'], textarea[form='test']");
let submitBtn = document.querySelector('button[type="button"]');

for(var i = 0; i < checkValue.length; i++) {
  checkValue[i].addEventListener('input', formAlert);
  checkValue[i].addEventListener('change', formAlert);
}
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', onBeforeunloadHandler);
});
```

})();